# How do I add various indicators to different links in my document?

Tags: pdftex, citing, labels, links, hyperlink

Using Overleaf, I have a project that I'm working on. I have the following links in the file:

- Hyperlinks to websites
- Links to a list of abbreviations at the start of the document using

```
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=List of Abbreviations]
```

- References to other sections or figures in the text, through references using

```
\label
\ref
```

- Citations, using

```
\bibliography
\parencite
\textcite
\printbibliography
```

For each of these links, I want to have a different indicator.

So, for internal links such as references to other sections, or references to figures, I would like the link to be italicised.

For links to the bibliography at the bottom of the document, I would like for the link to be underlined.

A hyperlink to a website I would like to be coloured in cyan, as is standard with hyperlinks.

I tried using

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=cyan,
}
```

to start with when specifying the link to a url, but when I do this, this labels every single link in the text with what I assume is the default for each type of link, including all of the above specified types of link.

I  tried to simply add in a \ulin{} around every citation, and to do \emph{} around every instance of an internal reference to another section or figure, but this seems like a needlessly tedious way of doing it, and I thought there must be something I could do in the preamble to get around these things.

Not to mention, \textcite and \parencite only hyperlink the date of the citation and not the author name, meaning that when I underline the citation, the author and date are underlined, where the hyperlink is only on the date. The point of the underline is so that it's clearer to the reader that the citation is in fact a link that they can use.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: by default hyperref only differentiate between links types (internal, file, url), if you want to split the internal links you will have to define semantic commands which switch the linkcolor locally. The author is not a link with biblatex because you would run into problems if you have more than one citation key which gives a compressed citation like `Author (2003,2004)`